# In Expression Builder, how do I format date as "Jan 01, 2013"?

Tags: reportbuilder3.0, expressionbuilder

I am using the Expression Builder in Report Builder 3, how do I format a date field as "Jan 01, 2013" or "Jan 1, 2013"?  Both are acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your field number formatting set the custom to `MMM dd, yyyy`